# Dependancy Injection in a static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing Unit Tests for an existing code base, and am still getting up to speed.

There is a static Logger class which is written like this (simplified):

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        var myService = new Service();
        myService.Save(message);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to Mock (using Moq) the Service class so I can verify the result.  But there is obviously no way to do that with the class as it exists. But I don't see how the Service dependency can be injected into the static class so that it can be mocked.  Is there a way to do that?  Or should it not have been written as a static class?

This is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293489/dependency-injection-with-a-static-logger-static-helper-class) as the service is not a static class.

Comment: You could also make the `Log` method accept `service` as a parameter

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker. True, but the method is called from many places and it would be a bit of a code bloat.  The idea was a quick and easy to use logger.

Comment: you can mock static methods using Fakes Framework

Comment: @Sinatr, I read that, but it's a bit different scenario.

Comment: @GregGum: Kind of an anti-pattern, and I don't know what DI framework you're using, but you could create an overload of `Log` that accepts a `service`, keep the version of `Log` you currently have, and inside of `Log(message)`, get the implementation of `Service` from the DI framework. In other words, you'd unit test the `Log(message, service)` method, but keep around the `Log(message)` method

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, Ok, I see your point.

Comment: You are creating a `Service` object in your static log method, why not just inject that into your non static classes?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing.