# How do I add logging to a static class without losing the ability to unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, functional-programming

**NOTE:** I realize that this question is similar to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293489/dependency-injection-with-a-static-logger-static-helper-class), but I am asking about a specific case here, so please don't close this question as a duplicate of that one.

I'm trying to make my C# more functional, and have been reading Functional Programming in C# by Enrico Buonanno. One of the techniques he shows is a `Try` class, that allows you to handle exceptions gracefully. You can see the code for the `Try` class [here](https://github.com/la-yumba/functional-csharp-code/blob/master/LaYumba.Functional/Try.cs).

This is all very neat, but in a real app, I would want to log exceptions. As his class is static, I don't see a way to do it. As explained in the linked SO question above (amongst others), injecting into a static class either can't be done or isn't a good idea.

The only options I can see are:

1. Requiring the consuming code to create an instance of the `Try` class (not currently possible with his code), as opposed to calling the static method. This makes the code a lot less clean
2. Adding a static `ILogger` property to the `Try` class, and setting it before using the class. I don't want to do this, as the `Try` class will be used on both the client and server in my application, and the logger would be different in the two cases
3. Adding an `ILogger` parameter to the class methods. I don't like this for the same reasons as in 1.
4. Accessing the dependency resolver inside the `try` class and getting an instance of the logger. This would mean that the code that uses `Try` would also end up logging to the file, which is not a good idea.

Anyone any suggestions? The approach seems so clean and neat, but it also seems to be missing an obvious basic function.

Comment: Show some code to better demonstrate the current situation and then show the desired behavior. Should help in identifying the problem and possible a solution.

Comment: Why do you think “injecting into a static class either can't be done or isn't a good idea”? That's the standard way to solve this; pass an ILogger to your class and create a mock ILogger in your unit test that does nothing. If you're running into problems perhaps you shouldn't be using a static class?

Comment: This is snake oil, never pretend that you can handle every exception.  Logging must always be an optional feature of an app, in a unit test you'd switch it off or have it write to a specific place.  Look how .NET does it with the Trace class (separates the source from the listener).  And strongly consider a logging library like NLog or Log4Net.

Comment: Do you remember [that one time when Enrico created method signatures whose first parameter was an `ILogger`](https://github.com/la-yumba/functional-csharp-code/blob/master/Examples/Chapter03/Instrumentation.cs)? This would allow you to test static methods by providing a mock `ILogger`.

Comment: @DourHighArch The impression I got from that linked question was that it wasn't a good idea. Anyway, as I said, in my case it's a problem as the `Try` class would be in a project that's shared between the client app and server, so I would need two different instances of the logger. Without adding two `ILogger` properties (which is getting very messy), I don't see how I could inject anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant Who said I was handling every exception? This is just a functional version of a regular `try/catch` block. You'd want to log there wouldn't you? Same here.

Comment: @DanWilson Oh, I forgot about that! Yes, it can be done that way, but the extra parameter adds noise to the call. I was hoping there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have the static method create an instance of the class, as then call a private instance method that does the work? I'm not familiar with `Try`, but you could do something like this (warning - air code!)...

```
public class Try<T> {
  // Assuming NInject, but same applies to any other container
  [Inject]
  ILogger Logger { get; set; }

  private Try() {
    // stops anyone from outside this project from creating an instance of Try
  }

  public static Exceptional<T> Do(Action f) {
    Try<T> t = new Try<T>();
    return t.DoPrivate<T>(f);
  }

  private Exceptional<T> DoPrivate<T>(Action f) {
    // This is an instance method, so has access to the injected logger
    try {
      return f();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Logger.Log(ex.Message);
      return ex;
    }
  }
}
```

Does that help? As I said, I'm not familiar with his code, so you may need to tweak it a little, but I think that will give you what you want.

Comment: Wow, that's a great idea! I'll need to go and play with it, but it looks like the simplest and cleanest one so far. Thanks.