# Adding Serilog ILogger to a static class

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog

I'd like to add a Serilog `Log` to a static class in my program like this (`DataHelper` is the class name):

```
private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<DataHelper>();
```

But this leads to the error message:

> static types cannot be used as type arguments

Which makes sense. So how do I inject the logger (which is working fine in non-static classes) to this class?

**Update**: The answer to you referred question suggests that it is not possible. But according to Serilog's Github, [there is a workaround](http://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/886). I just need log to be aware of the class it is logging from. For now, it seems as if it is logging from the main class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency injection with a static logger, static helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293489/dependency-injection-with-a-static-logger-static-helper-class)

Comment: @nilsK the answer to you referred question suggests that it is not possible. But according to Serilog's Github, there is a way: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/886

Comment: what I would do, if you have a possibility, refactor DataHelper class and make in regular object registered as a singleton. It will simplify usage and testability

Comment: @OlegI Does that mean that every static class I have made, in order to write to log, needs to turn into Singleton?

Comment: @Disasterkid well, it's up for you to make such decisions if there is no easy workaround to fix your problem and writing logs are crucial for you

Answer (score 22):

You need to use the overload that accepts a `Type`:

```
private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext(typeof(DataHelper));
```

Comment: Do we not need `static` after `private`?

Comment: Depends on usage; I only made the minimal changes here to show the `ForContext()` overload in the setting of your code sample above. If the `_log` field is in a static class, you'll definitely need to add `static`; otherwise, it's probably a matter of taste in this situation. HTH!

Answer (score 2):

The discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/886) discusses this limitation and suggests a resolution. Summary: Use the overload `ForContext(Type)`, which you can pass the type of the static class using `typeof(DataHelper)`.

Comment: This seems to work but what should the value of `"SourceContext"` be? It logs as if we are logging from the Main class.

Comment: Beats me; I've never used Serilog.