# Dependency Injection in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with Dependency Injection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743951/help-with-dependency-injection-in-net)

Hi friends,

It is a couple of days that I've been seeing **Dependency Injection** in some websites !
Would you please say :

What is it ?
What's the benefits of using it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743951/help-with-dependency-injection-in-net.

Comment: Funny, the title is the same as the title of my book. Perhaps a web search could have helped you out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependency Injection is a very simple concept (the implementation, on the other hand, can be quite complex).

**Dependency Injection** is simply allowing the caller of a method to inject dependent objects into the method when it is called. For example if you wanted to allow the following piece of code to swap SQL providers without recompiling the method:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using(SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection())
    {
        // Do some work.
    }
}
```

You could 'Inject' the SQL Provider:

```
public void DoSomething(ISQLProvider provider)
{
    // Do the work with provider
}
```

There's also **Constructor Injection** where you inject the dependency of an object during instanciation.

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private ISQLProvider _provider;

    public SomeObject(ISQLProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }
}
```

The whole point of Dependency Injection is to reduce coupling between the pieces of your application. The caller can substitute whatever it needs to get the job done without modifying the method it's calling (or the object it's creating).

Answer (score 1):

Useful links :)

[Dependency Injection on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

[Dependency Injection on Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx)

[Simple tutorial on Dependency Injection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/dependency-injection/index.html)