# Dependency Injection in WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, dependency-injection

I am trying to bend my mind around WCF and Dependency Injection is a point that confuses me a bit.

My question is basically: Does WCF support Dependency Injection out of the box, or does one have to rely on some external framework for that?

If there is a way to do this using nothing but WCF, could you give me a link to a simple example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass values to the constructor on my wcf service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454850/how-do-i-pass-values-to-the-constructor-on-my-wcf-service)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/) by [Jimmy Bogard](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/) about hooking StructureMap into the WCF integration points that allows him to not have constructor-less service constructors.  I know that you're looking for a non-DI Framework, so if you use the approaches provided in the links from Peter K's comment to his answer and combine the roll-you-own DI container with WCF's integration points with [`IInstanceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) and [`IServiceBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx) as described by Jimmy, you should have a DI solution for WCF that doesn't use a third-party DI framework.

It's definitely isn't a 5-minute exercise and will require a bit of code, but hopefully this helps.  Let me know if you have questions and I'll update this response.  Good luck!

Comment: "It definitely isn't a 5-minute exercise" that says so much about WCF.

Answer (score 2):

WCF says nothing about dependency injection as such.  Usually you need to use a framework like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) or [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) or [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) or [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) to do it.

There are other messages here [about how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743951/help-with-dependency-injection-in-net).

Comment: You don't need a DI framework to do dependency injection. They can come in handy though ;-)

Comment: :-) True.  I was reading through [this](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2008/01/17/its-my-turn-to-build-an-ioc-container-in-15-minutes-and-33-lines) and [this](http://ayende.com/blog/2886/building-an-ioc-container-in-15-lines-of-code).  How hard can it be?!? :-)

Comment: After building one for a year, I can conclude that it is actually very easy ;-)

Comment: So, does WCF offer any control over the instantiation of the service contract implementation class, other than specifying the name of the implementation class? What if said class doesn't have a default constructor?