# How to Properly Test Controllers in ASP.net MVC that has database calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am working on an ASP.net MVC 3.0 Application. I am using `MSTest` along with `Moq` for unit testing. I have written all the test methods for my controllers and ran those tests , which gave successful results.

Now, I have a doubt whether I have properly made unit testing. Because, almost most of my controller actions contains database calls.

I am not mocking them , I am mocking only `Session` and `Request` objects using Moq.

Is it really necessary to mock database calls, since unit testing means testing a single unit of code? I think unit testing controller with database calls violates above statement.

If it is so, can any one explain me how to mock database calls? I am not using any Entity Framework.

**Updated2:**

```
[httppost]
  public void AjaxSave(Model m)
{
   m.update(); // Database call
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should extract code which makes database calls into separate object (take a look on [Single Responsibility Principle](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)). E.g. you have controller

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     { 
         var connectionString = 
             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString;
         using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             string sql = "SELECT Name FROM People";
             var command = connection.CreateCommand(sql);
             var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
             List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
             while(reader.Read())
             {
                 Person p = new Person();
                 p.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                 people.Add(p);
             }

             return View(people);
         }
     }
}
```

Extract data-access code into separate class (usually such classes called [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)):

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
     public List<Person> GetAllPeople()
     {
         var connectionString = 
             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString;
         using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             string sql = "SELECT Name FROM People";
             var command = connection.CreateCommand(sql);
             var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
             List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
             while(reader.Read())
             {
                 Person p = new Person();
                 p.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                 people.Add(p);
             }

             return people;
         }
     }
}
```

As you already notices I declared abstraction which is implemented by data-access class:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    List<Person> GetAllPeople();
    // other data access API will go here
}
```

Make controller depend on this abstraction (it's important - abstraction is easy to mock):

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
     private IPersonRepository _personRepository;

     public PersonController(IPersonRepository personRepository)
     {
         _personRepository = personRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     { 
         var people = _personRepository.GetAllPeople();
         return View(people);             
     }
}
```

Then inject repository implementation into controller ([Dependency Injection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743951/dependency-injection-in-net-with-examples)) and mock it for tests:

```
var repositoryMock = new Mock<IPersonRepository>();
var people = new List<People>(); // provide some sample list 
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetAllPeople()).Return(people);
var controller = new PersonController(repositoryMock.Object);

var result = (ViewResult)controller.Index();
// Assert here
Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewName, "Index");
Assert.AreEqual(result.Model, people);
repositoryMock.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky..can you please give me a sample test method

Comment: @Avinash welcome :) I also added several assertions to sample test method. Last one verifies that all dependency calls which you have set up for mocked repository occurred successfully (i.e. you can forget to get people from database)

Comment: @Lazyberezovsky..can you please explain about the test method , what actually is happening

Comment: @Is database call happening here?

Comment: @Avinash nope, you are passing mocked object. Which is looks to your controller exactly like a normal repository. This mock has setup for returning people without hitting any real database. So, if controller will ask repository for people list, it will get list which you created. And last line of test verifies that controller did ask repository for people.

Comment: @Lazyberezovsky..thanks for explanation.I understood now. So, inorder to test database methods , i need to test model methods?

Comment: I don't understand one thing - in the PersonController, how does it do what it's supposed to do? All it references is the interface, where does the repository come in on runtime?

Comment: I think one thing is missing in your answer. You need to mention that the default constructor is also needed, or the controller doesn't fetch the actual context.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you have some design issues here because proper testable code will never end up with database code inside an MVC Controller, you need to better implement separation of concerns so that each piece of code is unit testable, and this is achieve by using some design patterns such as Service Factory, Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control...Joel Abrahamsson explains it pretty well [here](http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/) in case your not aware of what I'm talking about. You can even check out [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), a pretty good open source tool for this purpose (Inversion of Control)

You can still unit test you controllers with a bit of effort, implementing set-up functions and clean-up functions in your unit tests. But, I strongly recommend, if you have a bit of time, REFACTOR your code, you won't get very far with some many unnecessary dependencies.

Leo

Comment: @leo..how to call model from controller

Comment: @Leo..i am not directly calling database , rather i am calling using model methods.

Answer (score 1):

A controller **never** should call the database directly (one - not the most important - reason for that is that this makes the controller almost impossible to test...). Instead, I strongly advise you to **refactor** your code to enable testability in the first place and also to have proper [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): Put all your data access code into [Repositories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) which you then access in your controllers via interfaces. This way, you can easiliy mock them with Moq.

Comment: @Thomas..Please find updated part of my question, This is how, i am currently doing. On Click of save , i am making an ajax call , that gets the updated model. then i am calling model.update() to save those values to database. How should i refactor above method.Please suggest.